# Cover half of the words vertically in a list with CSS

Tags: html, css

I was asked to create a simple `unordered list`.

The hard part is that each word inside of that list must be covered 50% vertically like the image below:

[image]

Obviously, instead of the ruler, I must do this effect with `CSS`. And I have no idea how to do this.  Any ideas ?

Comment: The best way to think about it is that you're not covering the words in the list like it's a highlighter, but you're creating a separate content box in the same space as the list and changing the color of that. Which is what @afelixj showed below. After the list is created, new content is put in, in the form of a blank box with 50% of the vertical height and a background-color of your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
li{
  position: relative;
}
li:after{
 background: #FFF;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Sample link</li>
  <li>Sample link</li>
  <li>Sample link</li>
  <li>Sample link</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
  <style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cover_div{    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;

    width: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;}


</style>
   </head>



    <body>

    <div class="cover_div"></div>

 <div class="menu">
   <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

   </body>
</html>
```